# Simple Joining SQL on two fields

Tags: mysql, sql

Basic SQL question -- and I'm new at this, so please bear with me...

I'm trying to join two fields in this manner:

'Buyers' table:

```
Name    Date
Greg    Jan 01
John    Jan 01
Greg    Jan 02
```

'Purchases' table:

```
Name    Date     Product    Qty
Greg    Jan 01   Apple      2
Greg    Jan 01   Banana     3
John    Jan 01   Apple      2
Greg    Jan 02   Banana     1
```

Joined table:

```
Name   Date    Apples   Bananas
Greg   Jan 01  2        3
John   Jan 01  2        0
Greg   Jan 02  0        1
```

I know it has to be something simple, but I'm just not getting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to `pivot` your results.  You can achieve this using `sum` with `case`:

```
select b.name, 
    b.date, 
    sum(case when product='Apple' then qty end) Apples,
    sum(case when product='Banana' then qty end) Bananas
from buyers b
    join purchases p on b.name = p.name and b.date = p.date
group by b.name, 
    b.date
```

Comment: It is worth noting that an If statement would also work
`SUM(IF(product='Apples',qty,0)) Apples`

Comment: You should not always consider the data to be always 'Apple' and 'Banana'. Even it contains only Apple and Banana, a slightest typo will make the query inaccurate.

Comment: And querying directly with the string or text value of the data, unless you are searching for some text from that column, is not practically a very good design.

Comment: @elzaer -- I agree, `if` works just as well as `case`.  Thanks!

Comment: @YeMon -- Agreed, but this is a common solution to pivoting tables. Just hoping to help the OP.  Cheers!

Comment: "Pivot"ing was the concept I was trying to grasp at!  Thanks to everyone for their responses.

Answer (score 0):

if Joined table names 'buyer_purchases',then the sql looks like :

`select buyer_purchases.*,Purchases.* from buyer_purchases,Purchases where buyer_purchases.Name=Purchases.Name and buyer_purchases.Date=Purchases.Date;`

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, your structure of the database is *quite* right. 
But, your desired result from these two tables is logically and conceptually wrong.

First thing is, you cannot put the row data into column names, unless you are aggregating it. 
 
Rows are always dynamic. Columns are static. 
 
What if your data contains strawberries and pineapples. 
 
Even you are sure of the data that it will contain only 'Apples' and 'Bananas', what if there's a typo and one of the values become 'Bannana'. Then you won't be able to get an accurate result from that.

A logical data structure for your case should contain three tables, 'Buyers', 'Purchases' and 'Products'. 
 
But, whatever your reason for producing this kind of result, the nearest possible result from this is only **grouping** 'Buyer' and 'Product' columns, and aggregating the product quantity.

But anyhow, try this query... It's the nearest possible for your case.

`SELECT B.Name, P.Date, P.Product, SUM(P.Qty)
 
FROM Buyers B, Purchases P
 
WHERE B.Name = P.Name 
 
ORDER BY B.Name
 
GROUP BY B.Name, P.Product`

In this way, you can know which buyers bought which products, together with the total quantity of each product they bought.

Wish you luck...